# Update data at intervals in nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I made a web application with nodejs, that is getting data from amazon. I want to make such app work on certain intervals. I wish to make 
- 15 min updates (will be for close to live inventory observation)
- Daily Updates (will be for some other data that doesn't change very often)

Would using setInterval be optimal? I read somewhere that setInterval results problems??

What else are the options that i have?

Comment: @JonasLochmann I've used your comments in my answer as I think they deserved to be part of an answer, hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: @Ibrahim kuş Has my answered helped you solve any of your issues? can it be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, using setInterval for 15 minute updates is more than acceptable, though if your looking to set events that will happen in say a weeks time then your better off using something like Node Schedule https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule.

The main reason for this is that setting dates far into the future or on a weekly basis as setInterval is that calculating based on time is sometimes not optimal if you have calendar based events or bi weekly occurrences or times where events deviate from there normal schedule. With Node schedule you can set events based on day and calendar events, so you could mix the two dependent on the situation.

Relevant for whole solution: setInterval will be a problem if you start horizontal scaling or if your environment (like Heroku) restarts your Server or if you want to do it at the next server start if the server was not running at the specific time. Then you would have to use a database. The database would save the time of the last request by which you can calculate the time for the next one' Jonas Lochmann

Comment: It was really helpful, I didn't expect such a fast answer. How would a database save my api request times tho? How can i reach such data?

Comment: The relevant part of the answer is because horizontal scaling involves adding more architecture so that you can spread out the load of a system this means that to have the separate systems work in sync you'd need a database that would synchronise the calls and act as a validator, though it's quite an advanced method.